# tinymce.selection.setContent inserts the text at the begining of the textarea in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, tinymce

I have created a plugin for tinyMCE to insert in the editor mathematical formulas using MathJax.
This plugin opens a popup in a iframe (using jQuery) and then launches a trigger - on event to insert the entered formula in the tinyMCE active editor.

My code is working properly in Chrome & Firefox (creates a `pre` that is inserted in the caret position of the textarea) but in IE the text is inserted at the beginning of the textarea.

I'm using the setContent method like this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(text to insert, {format: 'bbcode'});
```

I tried to use `ed.focus()` before inserting and other recommendations found in StackOverflow but nothing worked for me.

Also, I tried to save the caret position before opening the popup and restore it when inserting but did not work anyway.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLVED:

I know that it's not the most elegant solution but works for me.

Before opening the popup I insert a "span" with and specific ID like this:

```
var sel = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection;
sel.setContent('<span id="_math_marker">&nbsp;</span>');
```

Then, when the popup closes and the text is sent back to the editor, I look for the span with the marker then I select it and call `setContent`:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var marker = ed.dom.get('_math_marker');
ed.selection.select(marker, false);
ed.selection.setContent("TEXT TO INSERT");
```

This works for all browsers! Remember to delete the span if the popup is closed without inserting anything to avoid leaving rubbish in the editor.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the .selection part, so your code should look like

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(text to insert, {format: 'bbcode'});`

Answer (score 1):

In IE8 in cant get active editor, so need to focus,so use

tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var myField = tinyMCE.get("SMSBody");

    //IE support
   if (document.selection) {

         myField.focus();
         sel = document.selection.createRange();
         sel.text = fieldName;
    }
else if (document.getSelection) {

         tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(fieldName);
         myField.focus();
    }
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Don't works :( Now i'm trying to save the position before open the popup. I will update as soon as posible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used one of the jQuery plugin called jCaret for these kinds of situation. 
Worked perfectly in most of the usually used browsers (IE 7,8,9 with compatibility mode as well).

Have a look at the examples given in the link below

[jCaret](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php)

Thanks

Comment: I will take a look to your advice. Thanks!